# Function Keys on Logitech Craft keyboard do not work

Tags: keyboard, logitech-keyboard

I have a Logitech Craft keyboard. The Function Keys (F1 - F12) don't work as they should on other Keyboards in Windows. How can I make them work (and how can I configure them with my own custom features)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Logitech Craft keyboard (like a variety of keyboards these days) have overloaded function keys to provide additional capabilities, such as volume and media controls.

The traditional `Fx` functionality has been made a secondary feature of these buttons. The access those, you need to hold down the <kbd>fn</kbd> along with the <kbd>Fx</kbd>.

The <kbd>fn</kbd> is one key to the right of the <kbd>space</kbd> bar.

Comment: 1. What do the overload symbols on the function keys mean? There is no documentation 2. Isn't it possible to make the keyboard output NORMAL function keys as DEFAULT?

Comment: https://support.logi.com/hc/en-us/articles/360023361953

Comment: press the FN key and ESC. Do not install Logi Options if you don't need it....

Answer (score 0):

There is an option to "*Use F1 - F12 as standard function keys*" in the Options app but it disables the alt-functions altogether. Sadly this option doesn't simply switch between whether the user wants function key or media control focus.